# Issue with react and react-input-calendar when rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react-input-calendar(0.3.9) on react 15.1 to implement a calendar input

```
<Calendar  inputFieldClass={classes.logincred} placeholder='DD-MM-YYYY' 
format='DD-MM-YYYY' minDate= {new Date()} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

But when the component is rendered,  its showing functions instead of calendar.

[image]